# Moving down (xlDown) then right (xlRight) not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move down by using xlDown, and then right using xlright, however the latter seems to crash

my setup is as follows:

[image]

and my code is:

```
Function testY(ByVal matrix1area As Range) As String
    
    Dim down1 As Range, down2 As Range, down3 As Range, down4 As Range
    Dim right1 As Range, right2 As Range, right3 As Range, right4 As Range
    
    Set down1 = matrix1area.End(xlDown)
    Set down2 = down1.End(xlDown)
    Set down3 = down2.End(xlDown)
    Set down4 = down3.End(xlDown)
    
    Set right1 = down1.End(xlRight)
    Set right2 = down2.End(xlRight)
    Set right3 = down3.End(xlRight)
    Set right4 = down4.End(xlRight)
    
    
End Function
```

`down1/2/3/4` works ok, but `right1` crashes.

Why is this ?

Comment: I see you are calling this from a UDF. Why are you using `xlDown` and `xlRight` to select your range? What is the purpose of your code? I am sure there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: i need to process the matrices d4:k10, d14:k20 etc, so i need to understand their shape

Comment: So you want to pass `C3:M32` and get `d4:k10, d14:k20, d24:E30` as output?

Comment: i get passed C3:M32, which in this case contains data for 3 classes of products. I need to process these in turn. So, starting from C3. i need to pass the subrange d4:k10 to another function (accepting a range) for processing. Then, i need to somehow move on to the next matrix,  ie process the subrange d14:k20. Finally, i need to move to subrange D24:e30 and process that. I am using xlDown and xlRight because of the irregular shapes of the matrices i need to process.

Comment: We can get those 3 ranges. But we need to undertstand few things before we code. **1.** Why UDF? **2.** Will the `C3:M32` be dynamic? **3.** Can there be many classes or is it fixed to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use correct [direction value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection):

```
Set right1 = down1.End(xlToRight)
Set right2 = down2.End(xlToRight)
Set right3 = down3.End(xlToRight)
Set right4 = down4.End(xlToRight)
```

Comment: i am not sure why this was downvoted. thsi actually solved my question - how embarrassing

Comment: @user3203476: I downvoted it because this is not the right approach. But I guess you are ok with any makeshift approach :) Well it is your question. Feel free to accept it or upvote it.